# How to set panels/elements to be resizable by mouse?

Tags: wpf, msdn

Example: A `StackPanel` with two labels. After starting the application the panels have a fixed size.

**Question:** How can I set the labels to be resizable by the user by mouse?
So that the user can click on the horizontal line between the two labels and resize the sizes as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you might be talking about GridSplitter.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Left" Grid.Column="0" />
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                  Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <Label Content="Right" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

Btw, this is a great tutorial about layouts in wpf.

http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Check it out.